# What makes this library work exclusively with Atmega328P boards?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-pro-micro

I've been looking into libraries that read CPPM signals that I can use on my Arduino Pro Micro, and [this one looked promising](https://github.com/jmparatte/CPPM) ([github.com/jmparatte/CPPM](https://github.com/jmparatte/CPPM)) until I read that it only works on Atmega328P chips. Sure enough, I tried it, and it doesn't function on the Pro Micro as it does on my Arduino Uno. Why is this the case, *i.e. what does it have that the Atmega32u4 doesn't*?

> **Implementation**
>
> This library works only on ATmega328 implementation of Arduino UNO,
>   Duemillanove and similar, also Leonardo. It uses the 16bit Timer1. So
>   PWM analogWrite() on pin 9 and 10 are unavailable. The library Servo
>   is not compatible because it also uses Timer1.

I tried to do some research on my own, to no avail:

- [`Timer1` isn't specific to 328P, 32u4 has it](https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~medesign/wiki/index.php/Guides/MaEvArM-timer1)
- For all I can tell, there isn't any difference in the interrupt capabilities of the 32u4...
- [`ICR1` and `TCNT` are, again, features that the 32u4 has](https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~medesign/wiki/index.php/Guides/MaEvArM-timer1)
- [My signal is connected to the `OC1A` pin that is used as the CPPM source (*pin 9, `PB5`*)](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Boards/ProMicro16MHzv1.pdf)

I'm new to this kind of thing and really stumped as to what could be the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That library relies mostly on Timer 1 and, as you already noticed,
the Timer 1 of the ATmega32U4 is very similar, if not identical, to
the one of the 328P. At least similar enough to expect the library to
work identically.

I took a look at both datasheets and the only difference I can see that
can possibly affect the library is the pinout. The pins relevant to the
library are:

```
       328P  32U4
ICP1 =  PB0   PD4
OC1A =  PB1   PB5
```

The pinout of the 328P is hardcoded into the library. [CPPM.h contains
these lines](https://github.com/jmparatte/CPPM/blob/master/CPPM.h#L109-L110):

```c++
#define CPPM_ICP1 8 // Input Capture Pin of Arduino UNO is pin 8 - ICP1 (Atmega328 PB0)
#define CPPM_OC1A 9 // Output Compare Pin of Arduino UNO is pin 9 - OC1A (Atmega328 PB1)
```

CPPM.cpp has two instances ([here](https://github.com/jmparatte/CPPM/blob/master/CPPM.cpp#L311) and [here](https://github.com/jmparatte/CPPM/blob/master/CPPM.cpp#L328))
of this:

```c++
if ((PINB & _BV(PINB1))) // rising edge ?
```

If you change the code in these three places to match the pinout of the
32U4, I would expect the library to work for you.

You could also change that conditionally as

```c++
#ifdef __AVR_ATmega32U4__
    ...
#else // assume ATmega328P
    ...
#endif
```

in order to make the library compatible with both MCUs, and then submit
a pull request to the original author.

Comment: Excellent, when I get to it today, I'll try making that change. Thanks for the theory!

Comment: Hold on, what do I replace the `PINB` part with?

Comment: @ifconfig: `PINB & _BV(PINB1)` tests the state of the PB1 pin which, on the 328P, is the same as OC1A. On the 32U4 you would use OC1A = PB5 for the same purpose. The test then becomes `PINB & _BV(PINB5)`.